# Why can't connect jnp?

Tags: java, jboss, jms, jnp

I have a problem with legacy code. I have to connect to JBoss JNP URL with my **legacy** system the `InitialContext` resolves

client is HPUX

```
13:37:09.007934 IP IP-eth1.8093 > client1.58285: Flags [P.], seq 782928796:782928818, ack 2591269614, win 501, length 22
```

But the **new** system Red Hat executing the same code

```
14:37:02.314313 IP IP-eth1.rmiregistry > client2.53620: Flags [.], ack 3425926867, win 114, options [nop,nop,TS val 180199390 ecr 3814062816], length 0
```

My code

```java
Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
properties.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
properties.put("java.naming.provider.url", "jnp://1.1.1.1:1099");
contextoInicial = new InitialContext(properties);

factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) contextoInicial.lookup(Configuration.getProperty("ConnectionFactory"));
conexion = factory.createQueueConnection();
destination = (Queue) contextoInicial.lookup(Configuration.getProperty("queue"));
session = conexion.createQueueSession(false,QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
consumer = session.createReceiver(destination);
conexion.start();
```

Comment: Please explain the differences between your legacy system and your new system.

Comment: Its a HP-UX system with java 1.5  the new system is RedHat java 1.7 but I'd runned with java 1.5 with the same result

Comment: Are you using the same version of JBoss AS on both?

Comment: Yes it's the same server, I'd tried to start a simple JMS client

Comment: Seems like it's an environmental issue. Are you sure all the proper ports are open for the required network communication?

Comment: It's unusual, the telnet responds but simple javas clients returns timeouts. The same jboss has a webservice endpoint and the behaviour it's the same telnet ok but simple client ko

Comment: If the JBoss server and client code is the same as before then that only conclusion I can draw is that the problem is environmental.

Comment: But how is possible if telnet responds java return time out?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that question. My guess is that there's an environmental reason.

Comment: Yes indeed is an enviorment problem i'd tested in another linux redhat with same java and responds correcty on time